# Using > and variable file name

Tags: bash, heredoc

For the following bash script

```
sudo -u root bash << EOF
FILE="defaults.txt"
if [ ! -e "$FILE" ]; then
    echo "min_granularity_ns" > $FILE
fi
EOF
```

I get this error:

```
bash: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
bash: line 3: `    echo "min_granularity_ns" > '
```

Don't know what is wrong with that. If I use `echo "min_granularity_ns" > defaults.txt, there is no problem. How to fix that?

Comment: That link also mentions 'EOF' but if I saw that earlier, I wasn't able to link my problem to that. So, I think this should the topic should remain open.

Comment: It doesn't need to remain open. The answers in the duplicate work and people will find them by reaching your question via Google. It's how this place works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Escape the `$` to prevent the shell from expanding `$FILE`:

```sh
if [ ! -e "\$FILE" ]; then
    echo "min_granularity_ns" > \$FILE
fi
```

**Note:** This is not a great answer, but it does explain the problem: variable expansion before the here doc is created. So, I'm leaving it for now.

Comment: you don't need that, just use `'EOF'` instead of `EOF` to prevent variable substitution

Comment: Tangentially, also quote `"\$FILE"`; see [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)